# require_once :failed to open stream: no such file or directory

Tags: php, dreamweaver, require, fatal-error

I have this testing code in **"PAGE A"**:

```
<?php
require_once('../mysite/php/classes/eventManager.php');
$x=new EventManager();
$y=$x->loadNumbers();
?>
```

**"eventManager.php"** has inside a require_once:

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/dbconn.inc');
class EventManager {...}
?>
```

My folders structure is this:

```
mysite/php/classes folder and includes folder
```

If i test PAGE A in a browser i receive:

> Warning: require_once(../includes/dbconn.inc) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in C:\wamp\www\mysite\php\classes\eventManager.php on line
>   3
>
> ---
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../includes/dbconn.inc' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\php\classes\eventManager.php on line 3

where is the error?

Thanks
Luca

Comment: "Where is the error?", Lol? Have you solved the problem yet?

Comment: yes michiel..but i think it would be better an absolute path!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You will need to link to the file relative to the file that includes `eventManager.php` (Page A)
**Change your code from**
`require_once('../includes/dbconn.inc');`

**To**
`require_once('../mysite/php/includes/dbconn.inc');`

Answer (score 22):

The error pretty much explains what the problem is: **you are trying to include a file that is not there.**

Try to use the **full path** to the file, using [`realpath()`](http://php.net/realpath), and use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get your current directory:

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../includes/dbconn.inc'));
```

Comment: Just a note for Windows users: I had to change the solution above to require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'util.php')); This will also work in Linux as well.

Answer (score 7):

this will work as well

```
 require_once(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) .'/mysite/php/includes/dbconn.inc');
```

Answer (score 1):

`set_include_path(get_include_path() . $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/mysite/php/includes/");`

Also this can help.See [`set_include_path()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)

Answer (score 0):

It says that the file `C:\wamp\www\mysite\php\includes\dbconn.inc` doesn't exist, so the error is, you're missing the file.

Comment: it exists cause in dreamweaver is already linked to eventManager!!

Comment: Have you actually seen the file? Can you find it? If you open your text editor, select 'open file', and type in `C:\wamp\www\mysite\php\includes\dbconn.inc`, what does it say? file not found? Bingo.

Comment: @benubird : i have same problem, and i check file still exist in path.  what the problem that make that? i confusing