# Yii functional testing errors

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii

So, I'm learning the book "Agile web-dev with Yii", and example of functional testing from that book produces the error below:

> > Warning: require_once(Symfony/Component/Yaml/autoloader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\web\server\php\pear\PHPUnit\Autoload.php on line 69
> >
> > Call Stack:
> >        0.0004     326184   1. {main}() D:\web\server\php\phpunit:0
> >        0.0011     367616   2. require('D:\web\server\php\pear\PHPUnit\Autoload.php') D:\web\server\php\phpunit:43
> >
> > Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Symfony/Component/Yaml/autoloader.php' (include_path='.;D:\web\server\php\pear') in D:\web\server\php\pear\PHPUnit\Autoload.php on line 69
> >
> > Call Stack:
> >        0.0004     326184   1. {main}() D:\web\server\php\phpunit:0
> >        0.0011     367616   2. require('D:\web\server\php\pear\PHPUnit\Autoload.php') D:\web\server\php\phpunit:43

I've spent a lot of time to fix this error, and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [require\_once :failed to open stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116421/require-once-failed-to-open-stream)

Comment: I don't think so. I'm doing according to book. And that guy has another problem with his OWN test!

Comment: it is, the issue here is that php can't find `Symfony/Component/Yaml/autoloader.php`, have you checked that it exists and the relative path is correct?

Comment: I didn't find Symfony. It tells an error on line 69 Autoload.php.

There is:
69 require_once 'Symfony/Component/Yaml/autoloader.php';

I don't know which Symfony I have to install. And why it didn't installed yet. I did everything according to book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem while upgrading my phpunit.

This solved the problem:

*pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com*

*pear install pear.symfony.com/Yaml*

Then run:

*pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit*

Hope this will solve your problem.