# Can someone please point out why my require_once() function can't find the path? php

Tags: php, function, web-development-server, require-once

I can't seem to find the answer and I have asked everyone I know.

On my local server my code worked perfectly fine. When I uploaded it to a server, the **require_once();** function stopped working. My file system is very simple. In the main website folder I have: index.php, private (folder) and public(folder).

When I run the website I get this error

> "Warning: require_once(private/initialize.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/inbounf6/public_html/zampi/index.php on line 6"

This is what is on line 6: **require_once('private/initialize.php');**

I have tried every version of the file path I can think of and nothing works.

When I move things around and I put it in the same folder, it works fine. So I think the issue is going down a folder or in other words it isn't accessing the private folder.

Both the permissions for the private folder and initialize.php are 7 5 5.

Any body know what is going on?

Comment: what about permissions? who runs the server, wsho owns the private folder, what permissions does it have?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116421/require-once-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [require\_once :failed to open stream: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116421/require-once-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: You should use realpath(), and use dirname(__FILE__) to get your current directory:

require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../includes/dbconn.inc'));

Comment: Try permission 777 because some of system not allow access to web with 755

Comment: check for www-data file permission for that private folder and file

Comment: @Hetal 
After I added that piece of code I got this error:

Warning: require_once(/home2/inbounf6/public_html/zampi): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/inbounf6/public_html/zampi/index.php on line 2

Comment: @NishitManjarawala Even after I updated the permissions to 777 nothing changed. Any other guesses?

Comment: @SoorajNRaju Could you explain how to do that? I am using Bluehost. It is a pretty normal linux host.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `require_once('./private/initialize.php');`

Comment: Can you explain further why you think that this solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use magic constant [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php):

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/private/initialize.php'));
```

> `__DIR__`     The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to
>   dirname(**FILE**). This directory name does not have a trailing slash
>   unless it is the root directory.