# Database connection issue in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php

Issue Is with the database connection for an open source Project(PHP).
Everything works fine apart from the database connection required for login. Following is the error that can be seen after login.

> Warning: require_once(../mysqli_connect.php): failed to open stream:
> No such file or directory in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/airline-ticket-reservation-system-master/login_handler.php
> on line 44
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> '../mysqli_connect.php'
> (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/airline-ticket-reservation-system-master/login_handler.php
> on line 44

mysqli_connect.php

```
<?php
DEFINE('DB_USER','Harry');
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD','passpasshello');
DEFINE('DB_HOST','localhost');
DEFINE('DB_NAME','airline_reservation');

$dbc=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME)
OR dies('Could not connect to MySQL:' .
    mysqli_connect_error());
?>
```

[image]

Comment: The solution is in the error. File not found. Check the correct path of mysqli_connect.php(If that's a valid file) and apply it in the code. Also, please include the code which throws the error(In your case, login_handler.php -Line 44)

Comment: your `mysqli_connect.php` is under folder `MysqlDataConnection..` ,change your path to : `MySQLDataConnectionfile/mysqli_connect.php`

Comment: mysqli_connect.php is present in the subdirectory of the main project folder as seen on image https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK1gA.jpg .

Comment: sqli is under MySQL Database Connection file folder @Swati

Comment: So why are you trying to include `../mysqli_connect.php` then?

Comment: https://github.com/harryroshan/airline-ticket-reservation-system above is the project link .please have check and let me know.Much appreciated

Comment: @deceze Please include the correct path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [require\_once :failed to open stream: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116421/require-once-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @Shadow negative. There are two object of the same but for different components only. And  Also ../mysqli_connect.php line has been changed to direct path even now it is giving me the following error                                                    
Warning: require_once(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/airline-ticket-reservation-system-master/MySQL Database Connection file): failed to open stream: Undefined error: 0 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/airline-ticket-reservation-system-master/login_handler.php on line 42

Comment: @ArindamDeka you need to figure out the right path yourself, that's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to include the mysqli_connect file where the error occur

`require_once(../MySql DatabaseConnection file/mysqli_connect.php)`

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116421/require-once-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)