# Class not found but defined with namespace

Tags: php

I have a class called `DataBaseHelper` which is defined in the file `DataBaseHelper.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Company\Project\System\DataBaseHelper;

use Company\Project\System\RepoLink;
use mysqli;
use mysqli_result;

class DataBaseHelper
{
    /* some cool stuff */
}
```

Inside of a file called `helper.php` (with the namespace `Company\Project\System;`) I use the following use Statement: `use Company\Project\System\DataBaseHelper\DataBaseHelper;`:

```
 <?php

namespace Company\Project\System;

use Company\Project\DataBaseHelper\DataBaseHelper\DataBaseHelper;

class CustomHelper
{
    /* some cool stuff */

    public function getDownloadCount(): string
    {
        try {
            $query = "SELECT sum(count) c from downloads";

            // The next line is line 258
            $DBLink = new DataBaseHelper();

            $result = $DBLink->getAssocResult($DBLink->executeQuery($query));

            return $result["c"];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // TODO: Errorhandling
            return "ERROR";
        }

    }

}
```

Calling `CustomHelper->getDownloadCount()` throws the following error:

```
> [15-Sep-2019 07:48:09 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Company\Project\System\DataBaseHelper\DataBaseHelper'
> not found in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/system/helper.php:258
> Stack trace:
>     #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/manage/index.php(49):
> Company\Project\System\RepoHelper->getDownloadCount()
>     #1 {main}   thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/system/helper.php on
> line 258
```

Is there anything missing with the namespaces? The use Statement inside `helper.php` was automatically generated by my IDE (PHPStorm).

I do not use any frameworks.

Comment: Have you used any framework?

Comment: @shihab No I do not use any framework (i will add this information to my question)

Comment: in helper.php file you have used `use Company\Project\DataBaseHelper\DataBaseHelper;` shouldn't it be `use Company\Project\System\DataBaseHelper\DataBaseHelper;`

Comment: @shihab yes you are right - it was just a silly copy paste error here. I use it with `Company\Project\System\DataBaseHelper\DataBaseHelper` (Thats what the IDE automatically imported).

Comment: How/where are you loading the file with the class `DataBaseHelper.php`? Are you using any kind of autoloader?

Comment: How did you run your `helper.php` file? How did you make sure `DataBaseHelper.php` is loaded before you're calling the class `DataBaseHelper` in it?

Comment: @KoalaYeung the helper.php file is included in my index.php via the use statement: `use Company\Project\System\CustomHelper;`. How do I make sure `DataBaseHelper.php` is loaded? I think it should be loaded via the use statement or am I wrong?

Comment: @Fabian: The `use` statement loads no file unless you otherwise programmed it to. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A class is not available to a PHP file unless the class is:

1. Declared in that file; or
2. Declared in another PHP file that is [inculde](https://www.php.net/include) or [require](https://www.php.net/require) by that file directly or indirectly.

The [`use` statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) only declared alias for long namespaced class to have shorter local names. It **does not** automatically include any file. In fact, there is no default definition on how a namespaced class should be placed in a folder structure at all.

To automatically include or require a class file on `new`, you need to implement a register autoloader function with [spl_autoload_register](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) or have composer implement it for you.

You may reference [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57885929/372172) for more details.

Your PhpStorm is probably suggesting the namespace assuming you'd use composer in a way that follows the [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) standard.