# Warning: require_once(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp, codeigniter-3

i'm stuck in this message error warning, i have doing some solutions but not solved.
here like message error i face:

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:
>   require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\pustaka-booking\application\third_party/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php/):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: libraries/dompdf_gen.php
>
> Line Number: 25
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pustaka-booking\application\libraries\dompdf_gen.php
>   Line: 25 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pustaka-booking\application\libraries\dompdf_gen.php
>   Line: 25 Function: __construct
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\pustaka-booking\application\controllers\Home.php
>   Line: 7 Function: __construct
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\pustaka-booking\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\pustaka-booking\application\third_party/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php/'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pustaka-booking\application\libraries\dompdf_gen.php
>   on line 25 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Compile Error
>
> Message: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\pustaka-booking\application\third_party/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php/'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')
>
> Filename: libraries/dompdf_gen.php
>
> Line Number: 25
>
> Backtrace: and here are the code:

```
/**
* Name:  DOMPDF
* 
* Author: Jd Fiscus
*         jdfiscus@gmail.com
*         @iamfiscus
*          
*
* Origin API Class: http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/
* 
* Location: http://github.com/iamfiscus/Codeigniter-DOMPDF/
*          
* Created:  06.22.2010 
* 
* Description:  This is a Codeigniter library which allows you to convert HTML to PDF with the DOMPDF library
* 
*/

class Dompdf_gen {

    public function __construct() {

        require_once APPPATH.'third_party/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

        $pdf = new DOMPDF();

        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->dompdf = $pdf;

    }

}
```

Comment: Does the folder `C:\xampp\htdocs\pustaka-booking\application\third_party\dompdf\` exist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [require\_once :failed to open stream: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116421/require-once-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)