# Failed to open stream: No such file or directory, when using __DIR__

Tags: php, autoload

PHP is throwing this error when trying to access autoload: `require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';`

> Warning:
> require_once(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crud_app/public/vendor/autoload.php):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crud_app/public/index.php on line 6

The thing is that if I `echo __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` it shows `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crud_app/public` and the vendor directory is outside of **public**.
This is the path where `autoload.php` is:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crud_app/controllers/vendor/autoload.php
```

Any idea what is happening? This is my [**repo**](https://github.com/labanino/crud_app/blob/master/public/index.php) in case you want to look at it. Running PHP 8.1 and macOS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer to your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116421/require-once-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index.php` isn't inside `controllers`, you need to add that to the path.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../controllers/vendor/autoload.php';
```